# Check reified class is Parcelable or Serializable

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, parcelable, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have defined an inline method that provides a way to deserialize fragments argument.

And I need to check requested `Arg` type to choose deserialization method.

```
inline fun <reified Arg : Any?> Fragment.navArgParser(
    crossinline parcelCreatorProducer: () -> Parcelable.Creator<Arg>
) = NavArgsLazy<Arg?>({
    arguments ?: throw IllegalStateException("Fragment $this has null arguments")
}) {
    when {
        Arg is Parcelable ->   // ISSUE
            NavArgParser.deserializeData<Arg>(it, parcelCreatorProducer.invoke())
        Arg is Serializable ->  // ISSUE
            NavArgParser.deserializeData<Serializable>(it) as Arg
        else ->
            throw IllegalStateException("${Arg::class.java.simpleName} must implement Parcelable or Serializable")
    }
}
```

How can I check Arg is Parcelable or Serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arg is not an object so you cannot use `is`. You should use `isAssignableFrom` which accepts a class object

```
when {
    Parcelable::class.java.isAssignableFrom(Arg::class.java) -> //
    ...
}
```

You can also write some extension like:

```
inline fun <reified L : Any, reified R : Any> isSubClassOf() = R::class.java.isAssignableFrom(L::class.java)

inline fun <reified L : Any, reified R : Any> isSuperClassOf() = L::class.java.isAssignableFrom(R::class.java)
```

And use it like

```
when{
    isSuperClassOf<Parcelable, Arg> -> //
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried its vise versa `(Arg::class.java as Class).isAssignableFrom(Serializable::class.java)`

Comment: Hahaha, I made this mistake before asking here =)))

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to check type equality purely in Kotlin (no java translation):

1. checking if a class is a subClass of a parent class:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified A> checkSubclasses(){
    if(A::class.isSubclassOf(Serializable::class)){
        println("it's a serializable")
    }
    if(A::class.isSubclassOf(Parcelable::class)){
        println("it's a parcelable")
    }
}
```

2. finding a class type and then checking if type A is a subType of B:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
inline fun <reified A> checkType() {
    val argType = typeOf<A>()

    if(argType.isSubtypeOf(typeOf<Serializable>())){
        println("it's a serializable")
    } else if (argType.isSubtypeOf(typeOf<Parcelable>())){
        println("it's a parcelable")
    }
}
```

`typeOf` can be used in more cases yet
please note the `typeOf` function is still experimental.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems they're using `kotlin.reflect.*` package.